# How to set up Solr server for TYPO3 using DDEV?

Tags: solr, typo3, ddev

I have TYPO3 development environment set up using DDEV.
Now I want to add Solr server to it, and use Ext:Solr extension for indexing and searching.

How can I set up Solr server to be available from the ddev web container?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT:**
The instruction how to configure Solr Server for TYPO3 has been included in the official ddev-contrib repository, and can be found here:
https://github.com/drud/ddev-contrib/tree/master/docker-compose-services/typo3-solr

**The original answer:**

In order to configure Solr server for TYPO3 using DDEV you need to follow these steps:

1. **Configure Solr container**

   Create `.ddev/docker-compose.solr.yaml` file:

   ```
   version: '3.6'

   services:
     solr:
       container_name: ddev-${DDEV_SITENAME}-solr
       image: typo3solr/ext-solr:10.0.1
       restart: "no"
       ports:
         - 8983
       labels:
         com.ddev.site-name: ${DDEV_SITENAME}
         com.ddev.approot: $DDEV_APPROOT
       environment:
         - VIRTUAL_HOST=$DDEV_HOSTNAME
         - HTTP_EXPOSE=8983
       volumes:
         - "./solr:/opt/solr/server/solr"
         # If you want your solr to persist over `ddev stop` and `ddev start` then uncomment the following line
         # If you uncomment it and want to flush your data you have to `ddev stop` and then
         # `docker volume rm ddev-<projectname>_solrdata` to destroy it.
   #      - solrdata:/var/solr
     web:
       links:
         - solr:$DDEV_HOSTNAME

   volumes:
     # solrdata is a persistent Docker volume for this project's solr data
     solrdata:
   ```

   For more details about the configuration, take a look at ddev documentation: https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/extend/custom-compose-files/

   This configuration will create Solr container and make Solr admin panel being available through `http://<project-name>.ddev.local:8983/solr/` from your host machine.
2. **Copy default Solr configuration from Ext:Solr to ddev**

   Create the folder path `.ddev/solr`. Then copy 
   the Solr configuration and cores configuration from  `typo3conf/ext/solr/Resources/Private/Solr` to  `.ddev/solr`.

   So you should have a structure under `.ddev/solr`:

   - /solr.xml
   - /cores/
   - /configsets/
3. **Configure TYPO3 to access Solr**

   You can do it using TypoScript:

   ```
   plugin.tx_solr {
    solr {
      host = solr
      port = 8983
      path = /solr/core_en/
    }
   }
   ```

Comment: It works like a charm except that the index data is lost if you remove the container (quite logically). With ddev the mysql (mariadb) container is configured to store the data on the host system.
If you add a line to the volumes:

    - "$HOME/.ddev/${DDEV_SITENAME}/solr/data:/opt/solr/server/solr/data"

then the index data is stored in the home directory on the host system. You can now remove the container (ddev rm) and start it again without losing data.

Comment: @JigalvanHemert thanks for the hint, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Please edit for docker-compose yaml version 3.6 thanks!

Comment: Important reference for multiple solr cores: https://glamanate.com/blog/using-multiple-solr-cores-ddev

Comment: The current version of the docker-compose.solr.yaml example has a docker volume so the data is non-volatile. https://github.com/drud/ddev/blob/master/pkg/servicetest/testdata/services/docker-compose.solr.yaml

Comment: @TymoteuszMotylewski it's probably time to update this. 2 things I see right away are that it's not necessary to use two separate docker-compose files, use just one, as in https://github.com/drud/ddev/blob/42550e4eea5a26b01aaec85dc627ea50138e7a3e/pkg/servicetest/testdata/services/docker-compose.solr.yaml#L79-L84 - Also use a docker volume instead of a mount, as shown there. It would probably be better to just use the documented docker-compose.solr.yaml if we can. I'll see if I can get this going and maybe follow up with a competing answer :)